# Fullcalendar: Same event coming in several event sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullcalendar

I have several event sources returning the same event. This happens because my event sources return events in a certain city, and some of the events occur in two (three, four, etc.) cities at the same time. I do not want to change the logic of tying event sources to cities, unless it's absolutely necessary.

Full calendar is displaying those events several times, in an overlapping fashion, same start, same time span, same title, same everything. Just several instances of the same event. As far as I know, events are uniquely identified by their id. I was hoping that Full calendar would know they were the same event by comparing the id, but it looks like I was wrong.

Is there any way to make a single event coming in more than one event source look like one event?

Comment: You will need to do your own filtering which would mean switching to using events function and processing the ajax yourself. Or combine sources on server and filter there before sending to client

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl If this is the only way to go, can you make it an official answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As charlietfl commented, there is no way to do it. I'm copy/pasting the comment for the sake of completeness:

> You will need to do your own filtering which would mean switching to using events function and processing the ajax yourself. Or combine sources on server and filter there before sending to client